# In a single cast with four dice what is the chance of throwing two doublets?

Tags: probability

In a single cast with four dice what is the chance of throwing two doublets ?

My working:

Either we will get aabb kind or we will get aaaa kind favourable cases 
Hence required probability is $\frac{{6\choose 2}\frac{4!}{2!2!}+6}{6^4}=\frac{2}{27}$

But answer given is $\frac{1}{12}$

Comment: I see no way to get $\frac 1{12}$.  I'd have said that "two doublets" specifically excluded $aaaa$ (just as "two pair" excludes "four of a kind") but even if use my definition you don't get $\frac 1{12}$.

Comment: To be complete:  my definition, clearly,  comes to the same as yours without the $+6$.  Thus I get $\frac {90}{6^4}=\frac 5{72}$.

Comment: The (*now deleted*) answer below was probably how the solution key you are looking at arrived at the same *incorrect* answer of $\frac{1}{12}$.  I agree with your answer in the post if we do allow four of the same number to count, and I agree with lulu's answer above if we don't allow four of the same number to count.

Comment: Just a reminder that even teachers and bookwriters sometimes go on autopilot and go with the "easier" "obvious" solution and make the mistake of not noticing that it is incorrect.  Mistakes happen, and good for you for not just blindly trusting the source and asking for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the $1 \over 12$ answer is wrong by both interpretations of "two doublets".  What leads to this "answer" is the flawed reasoning that:
$$P_{\,{\rm 2-doublets}} = \eqalign{
{\rm (*\,aabb\,*)\;} &(1) (1/6) (1) (1/6)\; + \cr
{\rm (*\,abab\,*)\;} &(1) (1) (1/6) (1/6)\; + \cr
{\rm (*\,abba\,*)\;} &(1) (1) (1/6) (1/6)\;   \cr
} = {1 \over 12}$$
Using a probability of 1 for the first occurrence of b means that b *can* be the same as a. But in that case, this formula overcounts the occurrence of aaaa as it matches all three cases.

If you want to exclude the case aaaa, you need to use $5 \over 6$ as the probability for the first occurrence of b to make sure it is distinct from a : 
$$P_{\,{\rm 2-doublets}} = \eqalign{
{\rm (*\,aabb\,*)\;} &(1) (1/6) (5/6) (1/6)\; + \cr
{\rm (*\,abab\,*)\;} &(1) (5/6) (1/6) (1/6)\; + \cr
{\rm (*\,abba\,*)\;} &(1) (5/6) (1/6) (1/6)\;   \cr
} = {5 \over 72}$$
If you wanted to include the case aaaa, you would just add the probability of that occurrence to the above formula:
$$P_{\,{\rm 2-doublets(non-distinct)}} = \eqalign{
{\rm (*\,aabb\,*)\;} &(1) (1/6) (5/6) (1/6)\; + \cr
{\rm (*\,abab\,*)\;} &(1) (5/6) (1/6) (1/6)\; + \cr
{\rm (*\,abba\,*)\;} &(1) (5/6) (1/6) (1/6)\; + \cr
{\rm (*\,aaaa\,*)\;} &(1) (1/6) (1/6) (1/6)\;   \cr
} = {2 \over 27}$$

Comment: In 2 non distinct doublets we are getting $\frac{2}{27}$

Comment: Every thing is correct only in addition you need to see $\frac{5}{72}+\frac{1}{216}=\frac{2}{27}$

Comment: Ah! Found my error.  I had mis-copied a line in my mathmatica notebook, and wasn't calculating the proper formula.  Thank you.  Answer corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

Using the counting principle, I get the same answer as the question contributor:

$6+5+4+3+2+1=21$ different pairings of doubles which includes $6$ identical pairs.

There are $\frac{4!}{2!2!}= 6$ ways to get each pairing of different doubles

Hence $P = \frac{15\cdot \frac{4!}{2!2!}+6}{6^4} = \frac{2}{27}$